# std::map erase preserving iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing my own std::map, using a basic binary search tree.

The erase method is supposed to

> invalidate the iterators referring to element removed and preserve the
> validity of all other iterators

Yet here is what the BST "classic" delete algorithm is doing:

*If node to be deleted A has two children, "replace" A by its in-order successor / predecessor B and the delete B.*

In the end, iterators to B are invalidated.
So validity of "other" iterator is not preserved.

Is the algorithm I've found not suitable ?

Comment: A BST re-balances by shifting pointers around. Why would node B be deleted?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Because a trivial recursive function has no way of making the parent of the current root point to something else.

Comment: @eerorika - A non-answer if I've ever heard one. Keep a back pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica No. My primary point is that the algorithm and the data structure that is taught to beginners is the simplest one, and the one that doesn't require back pointers is the simplest. But also, adding a pointer to achieve reference stability is an unnecessary overhead when that reference stability isn't needed. Regarding 50%, normal BST node has two pointers of overhead. Adding back pointer increases this to 3. 2 + 50% = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the algorithm I've found not suitable ?

Correct. The algorithm that you describe would not be suitable for implementing `std::map`.